# Find values that appear in all lists (or arrays or collections)

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given the following:

```
List<List<int>> lists = new List<List<int>>();

lists.Add(new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 1,2 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 });
lists.Add(new List<int>() { 1,2,5,6,7 });
```

What is the best/fastest way of identifying which numbers appear in all lists?

Comment: are the lists sorted?

Comment: Have you tried different methods? You can check which is the fastest by yourself.

Comment: "which numbers"  Is the range -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647, or much, much smaller?

Comment: based on how the inputs look I would guess a array where you count the appearances and then filter for all indexes with maximal count

Comment: Can there be duplicates and would you want them preserved?

Comment: Fastest in terms of runtime, or in coding technique? If it is about run-time, then why not simply take the smallest list and check for each member its existence in all the others?

Comment: @A.S.H why spend O(n) time finding which list is smaller, when you could potentially have a smaller set after the first intersection anyway, e.g. if you put the lists `{ 2, 3, 4}` and `{1, 2, 8, 42}` in the front of the lists in the question, while they're both larger than the smallest list, after they're processed the working set is `{1}` and so already smaller than the smallest list. Finding the smallest doesn't save enough to justify the cost of doing so.

Comment: @JonHanna I agree with you in the fact that finding the smallest list (or set, more precisely) is probably not necessary (we can start at any set). The point is that, do we need to find intersections of pairs? Doesnt it do more job than necessary? By proceeding in the simple way (elimination), we stop immediately whenever a member is not found in any of the sets. What do you think?

Comment: @JonHanna By the way, I am not sure we can say it is O(N), it is O(number of sets) if the used set's structure has a cardinality member, which is usually the case. Ok, in the worst case it is, if each set contains only one member, but in practice...

Comment: Finding the smallest list is an O(n) operation as you go through the n lists you have, with the only short-circuit being if you find an empty list (which indeed allows you to short-circuit the next operation too). I'm not following your other comment at all.

Comment: This is what I was saying in the second comment, O(n) where n is the number of lists. I guess the complexity here should be assessed in terms of total number of elements in all lists.:)

Comment: @A.S.H the complexity should be assessed in terms of whatever affects it. Still, the number of lists will be `n/avg` where `n` is the number of items and `avg` is the average number of items. As such, in comparing the lists will result in `n * (1/avg) - 1` operations, and so is O(n).

Comment: @JonHanna Good point thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do it for two lists one would use `x.Intersect(y)`.

To do it for several we would want to do something like:

```
var intersection = lists.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y));
```

But this won't work because the result of the lambda isn't `List<int>` and so it can't be fed back in. This might tempt us to try:

```
var intersection = lists.Aggregate((x, y) => x.Intersect(y).ToList());
```

But then this makes n-1 needless calls to `ToList()` which is relatively expensive. We can get around this with:

```
var intersection = lists.Aggregate(
  (IEnumerable<int> x, IEnumerable<int> y) => x.Intersect(y));
```

Which applies the same logic, but in using explicit types in the lambda, we can feed the result of `Intersect()` back in without wasting time and memory creating a list each time, and so gives faster results.

If this came up a lot we can get further (slight) performance improvements by rolling our own rather than using Linq:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
  using(var en = source.GetEnumerator())
  {
    if(!en.MoveNext()) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    var set = new HashSet<T>(en.Current);
    while(en.MoveNext())
    {
      var newSet = new HashSet<T>();
      foreach(T item in en.Current)
        if(set.Remove(item))
          newSet.Add(item);
      set = newSet;
    }
    return set;
  }
}
```

This assumes its for internal use only. If it could be called from another assembly it should have error checks, and perhaps should be defined so as to only perform the intersect operations on the first `MoveNext()` of the calling code:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
  if(source == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
  return IntersectAllIterator(source);
}
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAllIterator<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
  using(var en = source.GetEnumerator())
  {
    if(en.MoveNext())
    {
      var set = new HashSet<T>(en.Current);
      while(en.MoveNext())
      {
        var newSet = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach(T item in en.Current)
          if(set.Remove(item))
            newSet.Add(item);
        set = newSet;
      }
      foreach(T item in set)
        yield return item;
    }
  }
}
```

(In these final two versions there's an opportunity to short-circuit if we end up emptying the set, but it only pays off if this happens relatively often, otherwise it's a nett loss).

Conversely, if these aren't concerns, and if we know that we're only ever going to want to do this with lists, we can optimise a bit further with the use of `Count` and indices:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> IntersectAll<T>(this List<List<T>> source)
{
  if (source.Count == 0) return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
  if (source.Count == 1) return source[0];
  var set = new HashSet<T>(source[0]);
  for(int i = 1; i != source.Count; ++i)
  {
    var newSet = new HashSet<T>();
    var list = source[i];
    for(int j = 0; j != list.Count; ++j)
    {
      T item = list[j];
      if(set.Remove(item))
        newSet.Add(item);
    }
    set = newSet;
  }
  return set;
}
```

And further if we know we're always going to want the results in a list, and we know that either we won't mutate the list, or it won't matter if the input list got mutated, we can optimise for the case of there being zero or one lists (but this costs more if we might ever not need the output in a list):

```
public static List<T> IntersectAll<T>(this List<List<T>> source)
{
  if (source.Count == 0) return new List<T>(0);
  if (source.Count == 1) return source[0];
  var set = new HashSet<T>(source[0]);
  for(int i = 1; i != source.Count; ++i)
  {
    var newSet = new HashSet<T>();
    var list = source[i];
    for(int j = 0; j != list.Count; ++j)
    {
      T item = list[j];
      if(set.Remove(item))
        newSet.Add(item);
    }
    set = newSet;
  }
  return new List<T>(set);
}
```

Again though, as well as making the method less widely-applicable, this has risks in terms of how it could be used, so is only appropriate for internal code were you can know either that you won't change either the input or the output after the fact, or that this won't matter.

Comment: I'm curious. Why do you use `Remove()` instead of `Contains()`? Not that there's probably any measurable difference, but it still seems unnecessary.

Comment: @ReturningTarzan `Contains()` would be buggy if there were repeat elements in any of the lists. Consider with just the two lists `{1, 2}` and `{1, 3, 1, 1}`. The correct result is `{1}` but if we did `Contains()` we'd get `{1, 1, 1}`. (To make things even worse we'd get different results if we tried the lists in different orders). `Remove()` means that the element won't be matched a second time.

Comment: @ReturningTarzan (It's possible to short-circuit on `if(set.Count == 0)` but that benefits some possible inputs and costs other possible inputs, so is probably not worth it).

Comment: Oh, I see. I figured it was to account for duplicates but I somehow thought you were iterating over HashSets and would never test for the same value twice anyway. Which is all backwards of course. Silly me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the .net 3.5 .[Intersect()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension method:-

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> b = new List<int>() { 0, 4, 8, 12 };

List<int> common = a.Intersect(b).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Linq already offers [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you can exploit [Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548651%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as well:

```
var result = lists.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Intersect(b).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't trust the Intersect method or you just prefer to see what's going on, here's a snippet of code that should do the trick:

```
  // Output goes here
  List<int> output = new List<int>();

  // Make sure lists are sorted
  for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count; ++i) lists[i].Sort();

  // Maintain array of indices so we can step through all the lists in parallel
  int[] index = new int[lists.Count];

  while(index[0] < lists[0].Count)
  {
    // Search for each value in the first list
    int value = lists[0][index[0]];

    // No. lists that value appears in, we want this to equal lists.Count
    int count = 1;

    // Search all the other lists for the value
    for (int i = 1; i < lists.Count; ++i)
    {
      while (index[i] < lists[i].Count)
      {
        // Stop if we've passed the spot where value would have been
        if (lists[i][index[i]] > value) break;

        // Stop if we find value
        if (lists[i][index[i]] == value)
        {
          ++count; 
          break; 
        }

        ++index[i];
      }

      // If we reach the end of any list there can't be any more matches so end the search now
      if (index[i] >= lists[i].Count) goto done;
    }

    // Store the value if we found it in all the lists
    if (count == lists.Count) output.Add(value);

    // Skip multiple occurrances of the same value
    while (index[0] < lists[0].Count && lists[0][index[0]] == value) ++index[0];
  }

  done:
```

**Edit:**

I got bored and did some benchmarks on this vs. Jon Hanna's version. His is consistently faster, typically by around 50%. Mine wins by about the same margin if you happen to have presorted lists, though. Also you can gain a further 20% or so with unsafe optimisations. Just thought I'd share that.

Comment: Quite apart from the strange idea of "not trusting Intersect", have you tried this code with the sample inputs from the question? I get a result of just the value `1`, missing the `2` it should also include.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I did test it, then I added the last bit to skip duplicates without changing the for loop. Silly me. But I fixed it and it should be fine now, so yay. As for not trusting Intersect(), I mean not trusting that it doesn't include an unreasonable amount of overhead given the context. (Also meant it somewhat tongue-in-cheek since this sounds a bit like a homework question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get it with `SelectMany` and `Distinct`:

```
List<int> result = lists
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Where(e => lists.All(l => l.Contains(e))))
                   .Distinct().ToList();
```

Edit:

```
List<int> result2 = lists.First().Where(e => lists.Skip(1).All(l => l.Contains(e)))
                         .ToList();
```

Edit 2:

```
List<int> result3 = lists
        .Select(l => l.OrderBy(n => n).Take(lists.Min(x => x.Count()))).First()
        .TakeWhile((n, index) => lists.Select(l => l.OrderBy(x => x)).Skip(1).All(l => l.ElementAt(index) == n))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: That's pretty expensive though. If you were going to use `All` you could use `lists.First().Where(e => lists.Skip(1).All(l => l.Contains(e)))` so that you don't need to check an item in the first list is in the first list, and don't need `Distinct`, though it's still relatively expensive because it still iterates each list for each item.

Comment: Still not going to be as fast as set-based operations, bar a few cases where yours manages to short-circuit to an empty result early.